# How to detect browser supports this HTML5 feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, html5-filesystem

I want to detect (using javascript/jQuery) whether the user's browser supports `multiple` attribute to `input type='file'` tag. A feature of HTML5 to add multiple images.

```
<input type=file  name="images" value=" " multiple=""/>
```

Please suggest me how can i do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var i = document.createElement("input");
if (typeof i.multiple !== 'undefined') {
    // supports multiple
}
```

Comment: +1, no need for Modernizr if you only need to test for this attribute.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `modernizr` which is developed for this purpose.

http://modernizr.com/

you can detect support of a feature like `placeholder` in this way:

```
if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {

}
```

Comment: can u show me some codes, after i have included modenizir.js in my page

Answer (score 1):

As taken & edited from the Modernizr source:

```
var inputElem = document.createElement('input');
var multipleSupport = !!(multiple in inputElem);
```

You don't need to include a complete library if this is the only thing you need.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Modernizr javascript library?  This provides a way to check if browsers support various features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#input), which does a huge number of these tests for you.

In this case, though, the test is really easy:

```
if (typeof document.createElement('input').multiple !== "undefined") {
    // ... yes, it has it
}
```

The same is true of all the other new properties on elements.